# how to convert to json from post in Yii2

Tags: json, post, yii2

I want to create json from multiple selection from listbox in yii2 after post i receive following data

```
categorymodel[0]=11&categorymodel[1]=12&categorymodel[2]=13
```

how to convert to json data and store in db.

json data like `{"11","12","13"}`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the proper array you can use  eg:

```
$retJSON=  json_encode($categoryModel);
```

Comment: Typo: there's a double $$